# Doble autenticación Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

estoy intentando hacer los siguiente.

En la web va a ver una área de cliente, para que puedan consultar pedidos, cambio de datos, etc. Esta la he construido con el auth que trae por defecto laravel 5.8.

Bien pero la web tiene que tener una administración con una `vista` distinta a la de los usuarios corrientes. Estoy intentando crear un modelo más que se llama `Admin` y hago la configuración necesaria como he visto en varios tutoriales.

**LoginController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $guard = 'admin';

    protected $redirectTo = '/admin/';

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.login');
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard($this->guard);
    }

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }

    protected function authenticated()
    {
        return redirect('admin/inicio');
    }

    protected function secret()
    {
        return 'Hola ' . auth('admin')->user()->name;
    }
}
```

**En auth.php añado lo siguiente, los guards y los providers**

```
'admin' => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\Admin::class,
    ],
```

**La ruta**

```
Route::get('admin', "AdminController@showLoginForm");
Route::post('admin', "AdminController@login");
Route::get('admin/inicio', "AdminController@secret");
```

**El modelo Admin**

```
namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class Admin extends Authenticatable
    {
        use Notifiable;

        protected $guard = 'admin';

        protected $fillable = [
            'name', 'email', 'password',
        ];

        protected $hidden = [
            'password', 'remember_token',
        ];
    }
```

**Vista login admin**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Iniciar sesión')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-5 col-xl-4">
            <div class="card myCard">
                <div class="padSesion">
                    <h1>Incia sesión</h1>
                    <p>Inicie sesión para obtener acceso seguro a su cuenta Camas y Literas.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ url('admin') }}">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group row posRela">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right labelCuenta">Email (usuario)</label>
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror inputCuenta" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
                                    @error('email')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="form-group row posRela">
                                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right labelCuenta">Contraseña</label>
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror inputCuenta" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">
    
                                    @error('password')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
    
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                            {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <button type="submit" class="btnIniciaSesion">
                                    Iniciar sesión
                                </button>
                                <div class="col-12 center mgtop1">
                                    @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="olvidoContra" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        ¿Has olvidado tu contraseña?
                                    </a>
                                     @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Bien lo que sucede es que cuando voy a /admin me devuelve automaticamente al login normal de los usuarios, y eso pasa desde que añadi esto en el controller:

```
protected function authenticated()
    {
        return redirect('admin/inicio');
    }
```

Eso lo añadi por si alguien intenta acceder a admin/inicio le lleve al login de admin.

Si no pongo esto el login admin funciona bien con su tabla, pero cualquiera puede acceder a admin/inicio.

Así que no esta funcionando como debe.

Gracias

Comment: Me parece que te complicaste demasiado, lo podrias manjear mejor con roles y permisos, de igual manera en los controladores si es amin te regresa a otra vista, no a la del cliente comun, en tu tabla users no esta mal que esten tus administradores y clientes siempre y cuando le hagas referencia a quien es administrador y quien no

Comment: Como referencia extra usmeando el profesor Jorge hizo un video acerca de lo que mencionas, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vxh2ikaydfo

Comment: Hola gracias por tu aporte @Dohko19 este video ya lo estuve siguiendo pero sin conseguir los resultados que quiero, no se si tiene algo que ver la versión. Seria más facil con roles y permisos?? no  quiero que alguien registrado en la web pueda ver el admin... Si es así como puedo hacerlo? llevo ya unas cuantas horas y lo borre todo al final viendo que no funciona

Comment: Es ciertpo que ciertas cosas cambiaron desde la version 5.4 a 5.8 pero no deberias tener ningun problema , si es necesario autenticarte con otra tabla,  una cosa en `LoginController` es el que trae por defecto laravel?

Comment: Si correcto es `LoginController` . Probe todo lo que decia Jorge pero no funcionaba correctamente

Comment: Te muestra algun error?, y por ultimio puedes poner la vista de login de administrador/?

Comment: Borre todo lo que tenia, pero la vista del login del administrador no, la añado a la pregunta

Comment: El login de los admins me funcionaba bien, lo que me pasaba es que si entraba en admin y ya estaba logueado me seguia saliendo el formulario, si entraba por ejemplo a admin/inicio sin estar logueado me devuelve el login que tienen los usuarios normales.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109217/discussion-between-dohko19-and-miguel).

Comment: Si tu aplicacion es pequeña y de bajo impacto, si puedes utilizar roles y permisos, pero si crees que es una aplicacion que tiende a crecer y sera de alto impacto, debes de crear otro proyecto muy separado del sistema anterior, y la comunicacion seria por medio de una API o microservicio.

Comment: Hola @Dohko19 he conseguido una solución, mirala si quieres y me cometas. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publico como lo he solucionado, espero que alguien lo pueda revisar a ver si es correcto.

**Admin Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $guard = 'admin';

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.login');
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard($this->guard);
    }

    protected function authenticated()
    {
        return redirect()->route('admin');
    }

    protected function index()
    {
        return view("admin.index");
    }
}
```

**En auth.php**

```
    'admin' => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\Admin::class,
    ],
```

**Rutas protegidas para los clientes normales**
Aquí dentro metemos todas las rutas que queremos proteger para los clientes. Esta esta hecha con el auth que trae por defecto Laravel.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('mi-cuenta', "Web@miCuenta")->name('web.mi-cuenta');
});
```

**Rutas protegidas para la administración y sus vistas**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.admin']], function () {
    Route::get('admin', "AdminController@index")->name('admin');
});
```

**Rutas para el login de administradores**

```
Route::get('admin/login', "AdminController@showLoginForm")->name('view.login.admin');
Route::post('admin', "AdminController@login");
```

**El modelo Admin no lo he utilizado**

```
namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class Admin extends Authenticatable
    {

    }
```

Después he creado un middleware para los administradores:

```
php artisan make:middleware AuthAdmins
```

**AuthAdmins**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class AuthAdmins
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (false == Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
            return redirect()->route('view.login.admin');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Por todo lo que he comprobado funciona correcto, el área de clientes normales funciona perfecto.
Si entramos a `admin` o a cualquier ruta que de admin, si no estoy logueado me lleva al login de administradores. Una vez me logueo me devuelve la vista admin y ya cargo la información que quiera.

**Pero me surge algo**

¿Como gestiono el cierre de sesiones, ya que si cierro la de usuario normales así:

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logout').submit()" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Cerrar sesión</a>
    <form action="{{ route('logout') }}" id="logout" style="display: none" method="post">
        @csrf
    </form>
```

Me cierra la sesión de usuario normal y la de administración.

¿como puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Es lo mismo debes apuntar al controlador de administrador por ejemplo `route(admin.logout)` el metodo o la funcion logout la puedes sacar del controlador base `AuthenticateUsers`, esta es la funcion pero es de laravel 7 desconozco en laravel 5, podrias buscarlo en tu proyecto: https://pastebin.com/ChJhf1Mn